# How to show the total as last row in a result set which contains the union of multiple selects from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below tables.

CREATE TABLE employee (
    interface_name   NVARCHAR2(80),
    rule_name        NVARCHAR2(255)
);

INSERT ALL  INTO employee ( interface_name, rule_name) VALUES ('EMP01', 'Invalid dept')

INTO employee ( interface_name, rule_name) VALUES ('EMP01', 'Invalid dept')

SELECT * FROM dual;

CREATE TABLE department (
    interface_name   NVARCHAR2(80),
    rule_name        NVARCHAR2(255)
);

INSERT ALL  INTO department ( interface_name, rule_name) VALUES ('DEPT01', 'Missing Dept id')

INTO department ( interface_name, rule_name) VALUES ('DEPT01', 'Missing Dept id')

INTO department ( interface_name, rule_name) VALUES ('DEPT01', 'Missing Dept id')

SELECT * FROM dual;

and I would like to get an output like this from the above tables.

```
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|   INTERFACE_NAME    |     RULE_NAME    |   ERROR_COUNT  |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|       EMP01         |   Invalid dept   |      2         |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|       DEPT01        | Missing Dept id  |      3         |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|       Total         |         -        |      5         |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
```

But while executing the below query

```
select coalesce(interface_name,to_nchar( 'Total')) as interface_name, coalesce( rule_name,to_nchar('-')) as rule_name, to_number(sum(error_count)) as error_count
from (
    SELECT interface_name, rule_name, COUNT(*) error_count FROM emp_error GROUP BY interface_name, rule_name
    UNION 
    SELECT interface_name, rule_name, COUNT(*) error_count FROM dept_error GROUP BY interface_name, rule_name
    ) t
group by rollup(interface_name,rule_name,error_count);
```

I'm getting the below.

```
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|   INTERFACE_NAME    |     RULE_NAME    |   ERROR_COUNT  |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|       EMP01         |   Invalid dept   |      2         |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|       EMP01         |   Invalid dept   |      2         |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|       EMP01         |         -        |      2         |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|       DEPT01        | Missing Dept id  |      3         |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|       DEPT01        | Missing Dept id  |      3         |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|       DEPT01        |         -        |      3         |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|       Total         |         -        |      5         |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
```

What is the error in this query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rollup`](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-rollup/) :

```
select coalesce(interface_name, 'Total') as interface_name, sum(error_cnt) as error_count
from (select interface_name, count(*) as error_cnt
      from employee e 
      group by interface_name union all
      select interface_name, count(*) 
      from Department d 
      group by interface_name as
    ) t
group by rollup(interface_name);
```

Comment: @Adriaan  What if I have one more column in my table? I tried with a query which I mentioned in the question. But not getting the expected result.